# Array de elementos checkbox

Tags: php, html

#### Cenário teste

Formulário dinâmico:

```js
function addReg(){

  const template = $('#formX > div').last();
  const novo = template.clone();
  $(template).find('select').each(function(i) {
    $(novo).find("select").eq(i).val($(this).val());
  });
  novo.find('.form-group > label').remove();
  novo.find('.form-check-inline').removeAttr('style');
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="post" action="action.php" target="_blank">
    <div id="registro" class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group mr-2">
       <label for="item">Item</label>
       <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item[]">
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 30px;">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bf" value="S" name="bf[]" tabindex="-1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
</div>

</div>
```

---

#### Problema

Quando é selecionado o `checkbox`, ele leva o valor. Quando não, ele não leva.

Dessa forma, fica incorreta a referência entre os registros.

---

#### Exemplo

[image: lançamento]

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 1
        )

    [bf] => Array
        (
            [0] => S
            [1] => S
        )
)
```

---

#### Esperado

A saída ideal seria:

```
[bf] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => S
            [2] => S
            [3] => N
        )
```

Ou até:

```
[bf] => Array
        (
            [1] => S
            [2] => S
        )
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- Quais a possíveis soluções para utilizar `array` com `checkbox` neste caso?
- Tem como definir o valor do `checkbox` quando não marcado?

Comment: Ao invés de usar os nomes `item[]` e `bf[]`, use `registros[0][item]` e `registros[0][bf]`, assim no PHP você terá um `$_POST['registros']` que será um *array* de *array* associativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie array com índices alterando o `name` do `select` e do `checkbox` incrementando `+1` ao valor nos colchetes de acordo com a quantidade de rows.

Por exemplo, na primeira row, os names começam com `[0]` e à medida que você for clonando, o `[0]` dos clones seguintes vão sendo `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` etc.

Ao submeter com os valores exemplificados na pergunta, terá como resultado:

```
[item]
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(1) "3"
  [2]=> string(1) "2"
  [3]=> string(1) "1"
}

[bf]
array(2) {
  [1]=> string(1) "S"
  [2]=> string(1) "S"
}
```

No `select` e no `checkbox` da primeira row, altere os names para `name="item[0]"` e `name="bf[0]"` respectivamente.

E altere a função como abaixo (veja comentários):

```
function addReg(){

  const template = $('#formX > div').last();
  const novo = template.clone();
  $(template).find('select').each(function(i) {

     // conta as rows que servirá de novo índice na array
     var idx = $('#formX > div').length;

    $(novo).find("select").eq(i).val($(this).val())
    .attr("name", "item["+ idx +"]"); // altera o name do "item"

    // altera o name do bf
    $(novo).find("[name^=bf]").attr("name", "bf["+ idx +"]")

  });
  novo.find('.form-group > label').remove();
  novo.find('.form-check-inline').removeAttr('style');
  $('#formX').append(novo);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Criei um `checkbox` que fica sempre selecionado e oculto, que será usado para ser submetido, e outro `checkbox` que não esta oculto e tem um evento, este evento muda o `value` do oculto para "S" ou "N", assim o `array` chegará da seguinte forma.

```
[bf] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => S
            [2] => S
            [3] => N
        )
```

```js
function addReg(){

  const template = $('#formX > div').last();
  const novo = template.clone();
  $(template).find('select').each(function(i) {
    $(novo).find("select").eq(i).val($(this).val());
  });
  novo.find('.form-group > label').remove();
  novo.find('.form-check-inline').removeAttr('style');
  $('#formX').append(novo);
}
$('#formX').on("click", ".form-check-input", function(){
  $(this).prev().val("N");
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).prev().val("S");
});
```

```css
#bf{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

 <div class="row">
  <form id="formX" method="post" action="action.php" target="_blank">
    <div id="registro" class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group mr-2">
       <label for="item">Item</label>
       <select id="item" class="form-control" tabindex="-1" name="item[]">
        <option selected>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
     <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="padding-top: 30px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="bf" value="N" name="bf[]" tabindex="-1" checked>
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="bf"><b>BF</b></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <button form="formX" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3" tabindex="-1">Salvar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addReg()" tabindex="-1">+</button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wictor, testei sua resposta também, funciona, +1. Mas a do Sam ficou um pouco menos "ajeitada". Mas valeu pela força!